# Output bash variable with multiple lines to curl json

Tags: json, bash, curl, github-api

I'm trying to create a script that will use the Github API to post a comment containing the output of a command.  This output has multiple lines.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token oauthtoken" \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST -d@- \
https://api.github.com/repos/company/repo/issues/14/comments <<EOF
{
    "body":"$OUTPUT"
}
EOF
```

How can I output the variable in such a way that it respects the multiple lines contained within?  Now when I run that command, all of the newlines get squished on to one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the basic cause of the problem are the newlines, the issues is that the value of `$text` is not properly formatted json.

Follow this simple example:

```
test="
Hello
World
"
curl -X POST -d '{"body": "'"$test"'"}' http://server.com/...
```

to see new lines working.

---

To make it possible to send the result of arbitrary commands using json, you need to json-encode the text before.

Comment: I still get `Problems parsing JSON` with this.  I updated my question to use heredoc because that seems to work, but squishes my multiple lines together.  Doing `"'"$OUTPUT"'"` in the heredoc also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah because the ouput of `ls -al` is not safe to post as json. You need to json_encode it first.. Can try something simple like `foo<new line>bar` first?

Comment: Ah, that worked.  So if it's still not working for the command output I want, I need to run it through a json_encode first.

Comment: @BRPocock A single quote wouldn't be a problem. A double quote would be a problem since it breaks the json